# How to fit and resize an Image to View Container?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently struggling with some image resize in `React Native`... I have a container that has some Image inside of it but I need the image to resize so it fits completely in the small container (without cropping the image).

This is what I currently have:

```
container: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            width: width / cardsPerRow,
            marginLeft: customPadding / 2,
            marginRight: selectDeviceType({ Tv: scale(3, 0) }, customPadding / 2),
            marginBottom: selectDeviceType({ Tv: scale(15, 0) }, scale(20)),
            marginTop: selectDeviceType({ Tv: 0 }, 0),
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOpacity: 0.15,
            shadowRadius: 1,
            elevation: 0,
            borderRadius: selectDeviceType({ Tv: 0 }, cardRadius),
            
        },
        wrapperStyle: {
            height: selectDeviceType({ Handset: scale(77) }, scale(85)),
            width: selectDeviceType({ Handset: scale(134) }, scale(165)),
            aspectRatio:  AspectRatio._16by9,
            borderRadius: selectDeviceType({ Tv: 0 }, cardRadius),
            overflow: 'hidden',
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        },
        imageStyle: {
            aspectRatio: AspectRatio._16by9,
            width: "100%",
            height: '100%',
            flex: 1,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
        },
```

Container Class is the whole card section, and `wrapperStyle` is the image container... So as you may see the image is not resizing to fix the `wrapperstyle` property, instead of sizing automatically to `wrapperStyle`, the image just crops out. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show an image of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this, may be helps you

\  add resizeMode

```
  <Image
    style={styles.imageStyle}
    source={{uri:imageUrl}}
    resizeMode='contain'
   />
```